# threejs - Displaying a 2D image

Tags: javascript, image, three.js

Another threejs question. I'm basically trying to get a 2D image display on the screen when I hit a key. I've searched around but  I can't find a way to get my image to display properly and some methods I just can't get working at all. Of the times I do manage to get an image showing, it either shows behind my 3d environment container (in html) or causes the entire 3D window to disappear even though the images aren't larger than it.
I haven't really messed around with images so I'm not sure what I'd need.
I'm not trying to get an image display in 3D space, just an image to pop  up on the screen, like a menu or something.

Comment: You can add a plane in the scene and and update the texture on the key press

Answer (score 14):

You could also use a `THREE.Sprite`, very easy to implement and even if it gets created in a 3D space it always face the camera.

Here's a quick implementation example from the [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/objects/Sprite):

```
var map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "sprite.png" );
var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: map, color: 0xffffff } );
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( material );
scene.add( sprite );
```

And remember to scale the sprite to match your image dimensions (in addition to setting `camera.position.z` to something high enough, of course):

```
sprite.scale.set(imageWidth,imageHeight,1);
```

Comment: hey man, tried your solution the sprite is added to the scene but still cant see it, any suggestion?

Comment: @ToBe if you publish a jsfiddle I can help you

Comment: If your sprite doesn't appear to render it might just be 1x1 px big. Try setting the size of the `sprite` Sprite object after creating it (i.e. `sprite.scale.set(128,128,1);`). "Default is Vector3( 1, 1, 1 )" ([src](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D.scale)).

Comment: The size of a sprite if 1,1,1 can also be visible as regular (unless size attenuation is disabled), it may be related with the renderer settings either camera settings, like fov, and rotation. If the camera points towards the negative side of the image (means the image is in the back) then it will not work. Try to position the camera by +z "away" from the image, assume the image position is (0,0,0), lets say camera.position.set(0,0,10); Make sure the camera rotation is set to 0,0,0 also, to point towards the negative z axis.